# Databinding to ASP.NET DropDownList list in ListView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listview, drop-down-menu

Basically when editing an item, I want to bind its ProviderId value to the DropDownList's select value. DropDownList is getting its list of values from other entity `entity_List` as you can see.

Markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="aList" runat="server" OnDataBound="aList_OnDataBound" DataKeyNames="ListServID" DataSourceID="ListServCon" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" selectedvalue='<%# Bind("ProviderID") %>' >    
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlist" runat="server" Width="155px" AutoPostBack="true" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProviderID") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>    
</asp:ListView>
```

Code-behind:

```
if (aList.EditItem != null)
{
    DropDownList ddlist_temp = (DropDownList)aList.EditItem.FindControl("ddlist");
    ddlist_temp.DataSource = entity_List;
    ddlist_temp.DataTextField = "ShowText";
    ddlist_temp.DataValueField = "ID";
    ddlist_temp.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: @abatishchev Thank you for reformatting!!.

Answer (score 0):

If the SelectedValue is ProviderId, shouldn't this be:

```
ddlist_temp.DataValueField = "ProviderID";
```